# Построение графика (Flot, php)

Tags: php, jquery, json, flot

Здравствуйте.
Имеется проблема в построение графика с помощью flot.
На сервере пытаюсь представить данные в следующем виде (взято с https://eax.me/flot/).

```
$date[] = array('label' => $name, 'data' => [$someData]);
// (Дата в формате UTC => double)
//Где $someData - массив типа '1515790800' => 44.2
```

После всё это передаю в JS:

```
echo json_encode($date);
```

В результате получается что-то типа:

```
[{"label":"Name 1","data":[{"1515704400":"54.3","1515790800":"54.7","1515963600":"54.7","1516050000":"54.9","1516136400":"54.5","1516222800":"54.4","1516309200":"54.4","1516395600":"54.7","1516482000":"54.3","1516568400":"53.9","1516654800":"53.9","1516741200":"53.8"}]},{"label":"Name 2","data":[{"1515704400":"54.3","1515790800":"54.8","1515963600":"54.8","1516050000":"54.7","1516136400":"53.2","1516222800":"53.7","1516309200":"53.6","1516395600":"54.9","1516482000":"54.7","1516568400":"54.3","1516654800":"53.9","1516741200":"53.9"}]}]
```

В JS обрабатываю всё это следующим образом:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "getData.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(responce){
            var options = {
                lines: {
                    show: true
                },
                points: {
                    show: true
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "time",
                    timeformat: "%y/%m/%d",
                }
            };
            $.each(responce, function(key, value){
            });
            $.plot("#placeholder", responce, options);
        }
    });
});
```

В результате flot выводит только то, что указано в параметре 'label', кто-нибудь может подсказать в чём причина и как это исправить? У меня есть смутное предположение, что flot не видит параметр 'data' в передаваемом JSON`e, потому что data - объект, а не массив, как указано в источнике. Если это так, то каким образом можно не перегонять часть массива 'data' в JSON?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: в пхп у вас `$data` массив, в приведенном json тоже массив и вы почему то думаете, что это не массив?

Comment: а,  или вы про то что внутри data объекты? это, конечно, да

Comment: Да, именно это я и имел ввиду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на [документацию к Flot](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format)

> The data is an array of data series:
>
> ```
> [ series1, series2, ... ]
> ```
>
> A series can either be raw data or an object with properties. The raw data format is an array of points:
>
> ```
> [ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... ]
> ```
>
> E.g.
>
> ```
> [ [1, 3], [2, 14.01], [3.5, 3.14] ]
> ```
>
> Note that to simplify the internal logic in Flot both the x and y values must be numbers (even if specifying time series, see below for how to do this). This is a common problem because you might retrieve data from the database and serialize them directly to JSON without noticing the wrong type. **If you're getting mysterious errors, double check that you're inputting numbers and not strings**.

Где сказано, что передаваемые данные должны содрежать массив объектов (серий), а сами данные серии должны иметь вид массива из двух значений `[x,y]`. Также обращается внимание, что данные должны быть числами, а не строками (хотя вроде и со строками работает).

Так что да, вам необходимо сформировать данные в корректном формате. Можете сделать это как на стороне пхп, так и на стороне клиента. Первое пожалуй, будет удобнее.

```js
var data = [{"label":"Name 1","data":[[1515704400,54.3],[1515790800,54.7],[1515963600,54.7],[1516050000,54.9],[1516136400,54.5],[1516222800,54.4],[1516309200,54.4],[1516395600,54.7],[1516482000,54.3],[1516568400,53.9],[1516654800,53.9],[1516741200,53.8]]},{"label":"Name 2","data":[[1515704400,54.3],[1515790800,54.8],[1515963600,54.8],[1516050000,54.7],[1516136400,53.2],[1516222800,53.7],[1516309200,53.6],[1516395600,54.9],[1516482000,54.7],[1516568400,54.3],[1516654800,53.9],[1516741200,53.9]]}]; 
 
 var options = {
                lines: {
                    show: true
                },
                points: {
                    show: true
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "time",
                    timeformat: "%y/%m/%d",
                }
            };
            
            $.plot("#chart", data, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
  
  
  
  <div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 200px;">
  </div>
```

Изменение формата на стороне клиента может быть в следующем виде:

```js
var data = [{
             "label":"Name 1",
             "data":[{"1515704400":"54.3","1515790800":"54.7","1515963600":"54.7"}]
           },{
             "label":"Name 2",
             "data":[{"1515704400":"54.3","1515790800":"54.8","1515963600":"54.8",}]
           }
         ];
         
         
$.each(data, function(idx, v){    
   v.data = $.map(v.data[0], function(v,k){ return [[ +k, +v]]})
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

для пхп, например так

```
$someData = [ 1515704400 => 54.3, 1515790800 => 54.7, 1515963600 => 54.7, 1516050000 => 54.9 ];

$data = [
        'label' => 'name1',
        'data' => array_map(function($k, $v){ return [$k, $v];}, array_keys($someData), $someData)
      ];
```

Comment: Спасибо, как я и подозревал. Проблема в том, что я не совсем понимаю, как  оставить data массивом, потому что json_encode перегоняет его значения в json-формат. upd: да, именно это и искал, спасибо!

Comment: @hthis как раз дописываю про пхп

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, всё получилось.

Comment: @hthis добавил про пхп, ну а если ответ помог, то можете отметить его  как [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)